# Legality for nesting methods in Java

Tags: java

I am looking for a way to run a key listener while processing data at the same time that depends on holding a button. All I want to know is **Is it possible to nest methods inside of other methods?**

This is just so I can have a while loop repeat while still allowing the key listener to work by putting the key listener methods inside of the loop.

like so:

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class myClass implements KeyListener {
    public void myMethod() {
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {}

        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}

        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}
    }
}
```

**Is this possible?**

**If it is, will the key listener nested inside of myMethod() still work how it usually does?**

Comment: Why would you expect nesting methods to have the effect you describe?

Comment: No, it's not possible. Also it's a bit hard to understand what you are trying to achieve, but it seems that you are missing out on a few fundamental concepts of OO in Java. Can you update your question?

Comment: This is not possible in Java. Why not just create the methods inside of the class and then call the respected methods in the order you desire?

Comment: wait @EvanBechtol is it possible to call a keylistener method with the same effect as it being fired automatically?

Comment: @NicholasGreene not in the way that you have it arranged. You cannot create a method within another method. But you CAN call a method already defined inside of another method. Try defining those methods outside "myMethod" and then doing a function call to (for example) "keyPressed" from "myMethod". Do you see what I'm saying?

Comment: if anyone wants to know why i wanted to do this, view my account and look at my last question. the title has something do do with animations.

Comment: @EvanBechtol I guess I kind of worded that incorrectly. I know that I can call a method from inside a method. I meant that I don't exactly understand where I am supposed to get a KeyEvent to use to call the methods.

Comment: @NicholasGreene  I think you are confused on the proper implementation you are trying to achieve. Look at this link, it shows a better way to approach your problem. http://www.edu4java.com/en/game/game4.html

Comment: uggg, I can't find any difference between that and my code @EvanBechtol. Why can't I just call a function that returns what key is currently being pressed like in a single-threaded language?

Comment: Wow, I'm stupid. It's java, I can make a method that does that.

Comment: @NicholasGreene I'll post an answer. Kind of blows my mind a bit that you can't see the difference.

Comment: I meant my code in my game. This was just code I put together to provide an example for my question. @EvanBechtol Part of that code is provided in my last question.

Comment: @NicholasGreene Oh I see, check out the answer I posted below. I think it explains things more clearly. If you want, send me a chat and I'll help you out a bit.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class myClass implements KeyListener {
    public void myMethod() {
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {} // Not possible in java + no termination with `;`

        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {} // Not possible in java + no termination with `;`

        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {} // Not possible in java + no termination with `;`
    }
}
```

You might want to check out the usage of lambdas in Java 8, only if you are allowed to use Java8 for your stuff. Lambda doesn't solve your problem, but might help you understand whether you want the handler functions to be anonymous, but structured slightly better.

Answer (score 0):

**Working implementation** From: [edu4java](http://www.edu4java.com/en/game/game4.html)
Each of these methods is **declared separately** They are part of a class and they are called inside of another method **not declared inside of a method**

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Mini Tennis");
        KeyboardExample keyboardExample = new KeyboardExample();
        frame.add(keyboardExample);
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }


public class MyKeyListener implements KeyListener {
    @Override

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("keyPressed="+KeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode()));
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("keyReleased="+KeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode()));
    }
}
```

**Your implementation**
Doesn't work because you are trying to declare a method inside of another method; you cannot declare a method inside of `myMethod()`. They *must* be declared outside of it, separately.

```
public class myClass implements KeyListener {

//Your problem is right here
public void myMethod() {
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {}

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}
}
```

}

**Change your implementation to the following**

```
public class myClass implements KeyListener {

    public void myMethod() {
      //You can call the methods below inside this method.
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {}

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}
}
```

Comment: I guess I was  little unclear. I know how to make a key listener. But I need to be able to hold a button. I have a method that processes the data from the keyboard and it has a while loop to do that. But the while loop keeps repeating and my key listener won't work because, unfortunately, I guess the computer cannot literally do two things at once. See my last question for more details. (Java: Running An Animation While Still Letting Everything Else In The Program Still Operate)

Comment: Let me do some more research on this then and I'll notify you as I update my answer!